# Inserting values into the correct index(ascending order) of a standard c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to insert two values `num1 = 50` and `num2 = 80` into an array which has been sorted into ascending order. I cannot use dynamic arrays or lists. Also no structs or classes. This is for a class assignment so I must follow the guidlines. The professor suggested that I should create a new array, `newarray` and copy the values from my orignal `numarray` until I reach a condition which would prompt the numbers to be inserted where they would fit in ascending order. I set my loop up to run as many times as it should take to fill up my `newarray` and I set up the conditionals to check if the previous number in the `numarray` is less than `num` and if the next value is greater than `num`.  The numbers get inserted at the correct locations, however, inserting the new value overwrites the value that would be there. 
I thought that 
`newarray[newindex] = num1; 
newarray[newindex+1] = numarray[newindex];` would write the inserted value into the current index, and then write `numarray[newindex]` into the index after it.

I will attach the function below. Everything is self contained in the function except `numarray` which is just sorted values up to 100. Thanks in advance. Maybe walking away for a while will help me figure it out.

```
void insertArray(int* numarray) {
    int num1 = 50;
    int num2 = 80;
    int counter = 0;
    int newarray[103] = {};
    for (int newindex = 0; newindex < 103; newindex++) {
        if (numarray[newindex] <= num1 && numarray[newindex+1] > num1) {
            newarray[newindex] = num1;
            newarray[newindex+1] = numarray[newindex];


        }
        else if (numarray[newindex] <= num2 && numarray[newindex+1] > num2) {
            newarray[newindex] = num2;
            newarray[newindex+1] = numarray[newindex];


        }
        else {
            newarray[newindex] = numarray[newindex];
        }
        cout << newarray[newindex] << endl;
    } 


}



int main() {
    int numarray[100] = {};
    randomgenerator();
    read(numarray);
    printArray(numarray);
    searchArray(numarray);
    Delete(numarray);
    sortArray(numarray);

    insertArray(numarray);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

After input for you guys, I tried the function suggested, and it successfully inserts two values. It was inserting 0 instead of 50, and it inserts 78 instead of 80. I got it to insert 50, but I don't understand what condition is causing it to insert 78, or what would be 80. I tried writing it in the same format as the for loop to insert 50, but it doesn't work.

```
void insertArray(int* numarray) {
    int num1 = 50;
    int num2 = 80;
    int index = 0;
    int newarray[102] = {};


    for (; index < 100 && numarray[index] < num1; ++index) {
        newarray[index] = numarray[index];
    }

    newarray[index++] = num1;

    for (; index < 101 && numarray[index - 1] < num2; ++index) {
        newarray[index] = numarray[index - 1];
    }



    if (index == 102) {
        newarray[index++] = num2;
    }
    for (; index < 102; ++index) {
        newarray[index] = numarray[index - 2];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 101; i++) {
        cout << newarray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Once you insert a new value into your new array, the subscript you read from and the subscript you write to are no longer the same.

Comment: I thought that if I added one to the index it is writing to after inserting, it would write in front of it. I just tried adding an int variable which increased by one when the number is inserted, and i also wrote newarray[newindex+counter] = numarray[newindex];

Comment: Note: since your original array is already sorted, you can use a `bsearch` type algorithm to efficiently find the place to insert your new value by recursively breaking your array into subarrays at the midpoint and continuing the search in the proper subarray and copying the remaining subarray to your new array.

Comment: `if (index == 102) {
        newarray[index++] = num2;
    }` I didn't check all of the code but this is wrong because the biggest array index is 101

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the approach in general is wrong.

The new array should be declared in the function main where it should be outputted after inserting a number.

The function should not insert two numbers at once. It should insert only one number but called as many times as new numbers should be inserted in an array.

The function might be called to insert a value when the destination and source arrays are the same one array.

So I am suggesting the following approach shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

void insert( const int *a1, size_t n, int *a2, int value )
{
    const int *p = a1 + n;
    a2 += n;

    while ( ( p != a1 ) && ( value < *( p - 1 ) ) ) *a2-- = *--p;

    *a2-- = value;

    while ( p != a1 ) *a2-- = *--p;
}

int main() 
{
    int a1[] = { 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    int a2[N + 2];

    insert( a1, N, a2, 50 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N + 1; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a2[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    insert( a2, N + 1, a2, 80 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N + 2; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a2[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 15 25 35 45 50 55 65 75 85 95 
5 15 25 35 45 50 55 65 75 80 85 95
```

As for your code then for example this loop

```
for (int newindex = 0; newindex < 103; newindex++) {
    if (numarray[newindex] <= num1 && numarray[newindex+1] > num1) {
    //...
```

invokes undefined behavior because the array `numarray` does not have elements with indices 100, 101, and 102.

Also in general it can occur such away that the source array does not have an element that is greater than `num1` or `num2`.

Another approach is to place the inserted values in a separate array and then combain the source array and the array of the inserted values in the destination array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

void insert( const int *a1, size_t n1, const int *a2, size_t n2, int *result )
{
    const int *p1 = a1;
    const int *p2 = a2;

    while ( p1 != a1 + n1 && p2 != a2 + n2 )
    {
        if ( *p2 < *p1 )
        {
            *result++ = *p2++;
        }
        else
        {
            *result++ = *p1++;
        }
    }

    while ( p1 != a1 + n1 ) *result++ = *p1++;
    while ( p2 != a2 + n2 ) *result++ = *p2++;
}

int main() 
{
    int a1[] = { 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95 };
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    int a2[] = { 50, 80 };
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );
    int result[N1 + N2];


    insert( a1, N1, a2, N2, result );

    for ( int item : result )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
5 15 25 35 45 50 55 65 75 80 85 95
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, VLA is not supported by c++ standard, but compiler extension. And for multiple insertion array need to be allocated dynamically.

Comment: @TruthSeeker You are right. If an array was not preliminary defined with the required number of elements then it may not be redefined.

Comment: If list of element to be inserted known, Isn't it the right solution to sort and merge than insert individual element ?

Comment: @TruthSeeker This approach is shown in the second demonstrative program in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree whole heartedly with [@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) that your new array should be declared in the caller and passed as a parameter to your insert function. This is mandatory if you are using a POA (plain old array) as a new POA declared within your insert function ceases to exist when your function returns. You can always allocate storage for your array within the insert function and return a pointer to the allocated block, but even then, if you want to keey your insert function type as `void`, you may as well declare it in the caller and pass it as a parameter.

There are a number of ways to do an insertion into a new array in sorted order, and all are fine for small arrays (say 1000 or so elements). However, since your original array is already sorted, for larger arrays, taking advantage of that fact you can write a routine that is orders of magnitude more efficient. An efficient approach using the sorted array is similar to a `bsearch`.

There you simply compare your value to be inserted with the middle-element in the array. If it is greater than the first element of your array and smaller than then middle element, you know you will insert it in the first 1/2 of the original array. You can copy the entire second 1/2 of the array to the middle-element + 1 of the new array at that point and repeat.

If the value is greater than the middle element, you can copy the entire first 1/2 of the original to the beginning of your new array and continue your search in the second 1/2 of your array.

When your value is less than or equal to the first element in the subarray, you have found the insertion point and can set the value in the new array to the value to be inserted copying the remainder of the subarray to your new array beginning at the next index.

Similarly, if your value is greater than the end value of the subarray, you can insert the value at the end of range in your new array to the value and then copy the remaining value from the original to the beginning of the range in your new array.

What this does is dramatically reduce your worst case number of iterations required to find the insertion point and allows you to use a much more efficient copy to fill in the elements of the new array above and below the inserted value. For example with a 1,000,000 element array, if you start your iteration at the end and work back toward the beginning and your actual new element is the 1st element in the array, you will iterate 1,000,000 times to insert the new value and copy the remaining elements from your original to the new array.

Contrast that with the method described above where you are effectively bisecting the original into subarrays, your worst case scenario is 20-iterations max to find the insertion point, and 2-copies to copy the elements below and above the inserted value.

While you can do it all in one function, it helps to split the function into two-separate functions. One to find the insertion position for the new element which will make recursive calls (say call it `findinspos` which does not need the new array as a parameter at all), and the second function (say `insinsorted` that calls `findinspos` and then copies the remaining elements)

They could be implemented as:

```
/* returns index where v should be inserted in a for a given 
 * start index and an array of nelem elements.
 */
int findinspos (const int *a, int start, int nelem, int v)
{
    int mid = (start + nelem) / 2;

    if (v <= a[start])                          /* exit conditon ins at start */
        return start;
    else if (a[nelem - 1] < v)                  /* exit condition ins at end */
        return nelem;
    else if (v < a[mid])                        /* v in 1st 1/2 subarray */
        return findinspos (a, start, mid, v);
    else                                        /* v in 2nd 1/2 subarray */
        return findinspos (a, mid, nelem, v);
}

/* inserts v in sorted positon within the nelem elements of a with 
 * the results stored in b.
 */
void insinsorted (const int *a, int nelem, int v, int *b)
{
    int inspos = findinspos (a, 0, nelem, v);   /* get insert positon */

    b[inspos] = v;      /* set value at inspos in new array */

    if (inspos == 0)    /* if ins at start copy a beginning at next element */
        memcpy (b + 1, a, nelem * sizeof *b);
    else if (inspos == nelem)   /* if at end, copy a to b */
        memcpy (b, a, nelem * sizeof *b);
    else {              /* otherwise, copy begin and end of a to b */
        memcpy (b, a, inspos * sizeof *b);
        memcpy (b + inspos + 1, a + inspos, (nelem - inspos) * sizeof *b);
    }
}
```

A complete test program (that borrows the test array from Vlad from Moscow), and lets you enter any number you would like to insert as the 1st argument to the program (default: `4` if no arguments entered) could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

/* returns index where v should be inserted in a for a given 
 * start index and an array of nelem elements.
 */
int findinspos (const int *a, int start, int nelem, int v)
{
    int mid = (start + nelem) / 2;

    if (v <= a[start])                          /* exit conditon ins at start */
        return start;
    else if (a[nelem - 1] < v)                  /* exit condition ins at end */
        return nelem;
    else if (v < a[mid])                        /* v in 1st 1/2 subarray */
        return findinspos (a, start, mid, v);
    else                                        /* v in 2nd 1/2 subarray */
        return findinspos (a, mid, nelem, v);
}

/* inserts v in sorted positon within the nelem elements of a with 
 * the results stored in b.
 */
void insinsorted (const int *a, int nelem, int v, int *b)
{
    int inspos = findinspos (a, 0, nelem, v);   /* get insert positon */

    b[inspos] = v;      /* set value at inspos in new array */

    if (inspos == 0)    /* if ins at start copy a beginning at next element */
        memcpy (b + 1, a, nelem * sizeof *b);
    else if (inspos == nelem)   /* if at end, copy a to b */
        memcpy (b, a, nelem * sizeof *b);
    else {              /* otherwise, copy begin and end of a to b */
        memcpy (b, a, inspos * sizeof *b);
        memcpy (b + inspos + 1, a + inspos, (nelem - inspos) * sizeof *b);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a[] = { 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95 },
        nelem = sizeof a / sizeof *a,
        *b = new int[nelem+1] {},
        v = argc > 1 ? strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        std::cout << " " << a[i];
    std::cout << '\n';

    insinsorted (a, nelem, v, b);

    for (int i = 0; i < nelem + 1; i++)
        std::cout << " " << b[i];
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete[] b;
}
```

(**note:** the array `b` is allocated with `new`, if that is outside your assignment, just replace it with an array with enough storage to hold the original plus the new elements -- and don't forget to remove `delete[] b;` from the end)

Like I began with, for small arrays -- how you do it really doesn't matter, but for larger arrays, taking advantage of the fact the original array is already sorted can provide orders of magnitude improvements in efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

> The professor suggested that I should create a new array, newarray and copy the values from my orignal numarray until I reach a condition which would prompt the numbers to be inserted where they would fit in ascending order.

So let's do exactly that.

```
void copyAndInsert(int* numarray, int size, int* newarray, int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num1 > num2) { std::swap(num1, num2); } // ensure we write the smaller number first

    int * num1pos = std::lower_bound(numarray, numarray + size, num1); // find where to put num1
    int * new1pos = std::copy(numarray, num1pos, newarray); // copy the numbers less than num1
    *new1pos++ = num1; // copy num1 and move past it

    int * num2pos = std::lower_bound(num1pos, numarray + size, num2); // find where to put num2
    int * new2pos = std::copy(num1pos, num2pos, new1pos); // copy the numbers between num1 and num2
    *new2pos++ = num2; // copy num2 and move past it

    std::copy(num2pos, numarray + size, new2pos); // copy the numbers greater than num2
}

int main() {
    int numarray[100] = {};
    int newarray[102] = {};
    randomgenerator();
    read(numarray);
    printArray(numarray);
    searchArray(numarray);
    Delete(numarray);
    sortArray(numarray);

    copyAndInsert(numarray, 100, newarray, 50, 80);
    return 0;
}
```

If you can't use things from the standard header `<algorithm>`, you can implement them as follows ([adapted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) [from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) cppreference)

```
int* lower_bound(int* first, int* last, int value)
{
    int count = last - first;

    while (count > 0) {
        int step = count / 2; 
        int* it = first + step;
        if (*it < value) {
            first = ++it; 
            count -= step + 1; 
        }
        else {
            count = step;
        }
    }
    return first;
}

int* copy(int* first, int* last, int* d_first)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *d_first++ = *first++;
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use std::merge from the c++ standard library. It merges two sorted ranges into one sorted range. As numarray is already sorted, the only thing we need to do is to make sure that the numbers we are adding are sorted as well.

```
#include<algorithm>

void insertArray(int* numarray) {
int num1 = 50;
int num2 = 80;
std::vector<int> numbersToAdd{num1, num2};

//make sure numbersToAdd is sorted
std::sort(begin(numbersToAdd), end(numbersToAdd));

int newarray[102] = {};

std::merge(numarray, numarray + 100, begin(numbersToAdd), end(numbersToAdd), newarray);
}
```